# Unable to highlight text in UIWebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have been working on highlighting a text in UIwebview. In that I used canPerformAction method in which i call a javascript function to highlight the text. Lets take the text in my webview is 
"the part is so confusing and very sporadic".
Here if i select the text "so" alone there is no problem and it is highlighting the text.

But lets take i select more than 1 word like "so Confusing and" it highlights but it runs in to an infinite loop and its keep on calling the canPerformAction method. I could not figure out why it is happening.

In iPad if you long press on a text that will be selected. My method gets called here and highlights the selected text. Then if i drag the blue lines to select further text (i hope u can understand what i am saying) in that canPerformAction is called and it runs into infinite loop.

I am checking in simulator.

**UPdated:**
I tried those things that you have told as follows

```
NSString *selectedString = @"function getSelText()"
                                "{"
                                "alert('document.execute');"
                                "var sel = window.getSelection();"
                                "if(!sel.isCollapsed){"
                                "var selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);"
                                "document.designMode = 'on';"
                                "sel.removeAllRanges();"
                                "sel.addRange(selRange);"
                                "alert('document.execute 2');"
                                "document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#ffffcc');"
                                "alert('document.execute 3');"
                                "sel.removeAllRanges();"
                                "document.designMode = 'off';"
                                "alert('document.execute 4');"
                                "}"
                                "}";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:selectedString];

I have given the above code in webViewDidFinishLoad.

In CanPerformAction I gave
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

    if(action == @selector(selectAll:)){

        NSString *setHighlightColorRuling = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getSelText()"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRuling];

        return YES;

    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

}
```

While running in simulator the alert till the last "document.execute 4" is appearing but there is no effect in the webview